How to stop button onclick using javascript?
Is there anyone that can assist?
<div class="address-grid">
    @foreach (var item in Model.ExistingAddresses)
    {
        <div class="address-item">
                <button type="button" class="button-1 select-billing-address-button" onclick="selectBillingAddress@(item.Id)()">@T("Checkout.BillToThisAddress")</button>
                <script asp-location="Footer">
                    function selectBillingAddress@(item.Id)() {
                        if ($('#@Html.IdFor(model => model.ShipToSameAddress)')
                            .is(':checked')) {
                            setLocation(
                                '@Html.Raw(Url.RouteUrl("CheckoutSelectBillingAddress", new {addressId = item.Id, shipToSameAddress = "true"}))');
                        } else {
                            setLocation(
                                '@Url.RouteUrl("CheckoutSelectBillingAddress", new {addressId = item.Id})');
                        }
                    }
                </script>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>

I would like to check a few conditions before making a call, but I am unable to modify the function or button at this time. Could you please provide a solution? I would like to use load new js.
Many thanks in advance.
I'm trying to add some code under the function and override the old one, but nothing is working. I want to use load new js to accomplish this, and I can only do that.
function was built dynamically, I am unable to describe it. All I want to do is check a few conditions before calling my route.

It's not entirely clear to me what you mean.  You can't edit this code and instead want to write other code that overrides it in some way?  Have you tried defining a new function with the same name?

What is it you want to accomplish here? What conditions you want to check? You can just add if statements to the function. Your title is "stop button onclick". What are you trying to stop? Is this button within a form?

@Jeremy I am not able to change anything in my existing code,  I have a widget that I use to load new JavaScript code and check conditions before calling my route.
If the user selects the incorrect address, I want to show an error message and halt the route call.

Is this button within a form? Nooo

Can you change something or can't you? If you can inject, then something like this document.querySelectorAll('.select-billing-address-button').forEach(button => { const originalOnClick = button.onclick;  button.onclick = (e) => { /* Your custom code here */  if (originalOnClick)  originalOnClick.call(e.target);    };  });

yes, it's working but using this i am not able to stop route call

If you want to stop the default action - use preventDefault. To stop further propagation, use - stopPropagation .  Ex: function selectBillingAddress@(item.Id)(e) { e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation();}

nothing working
